# Can you determine a publications parent or child publications in the CD API?

Tags: 2013-sp1, api

Thinking about a language selector drop-down on a site with multiple languages and was wondering if this could dynamically determined via the publication hierarchy in our Blueprint from the CD API?

Secondary language publications inherit from a primary language publication - if I could detect this in the API I could drive out a language selector that could be nicely tied into when a site is actually published.

Comment: Although the API doesn't support this, you could achieve it with a clever numbering system. With the CD API you then get all PublicationMeta (which includes the Publication title)....

Comment: Good point - we already use numbering to order the child publications beneath their parents - this number could be extended to indicate which parent as well I guess.

Comment: Related to language switching is which page to switch to. There's an approach hinted at in the Tridion Reference Implementation in page `Home/System_/include/Header`. The `Language Selector Configuration` Component has a field for: "Default content to link to if there is no equivalent page in the selected language (if blank language home page will be used)."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible via the CD API since it is designed to work within a specific context publication.  However, you can publish your own hierarchy in form of XML similar to the concept of publishing PageList.xml for SG-based navigation.

Also check out this post on language switchers in Tridion: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/tridion-language-switcher

Comment: Thought as much. Might have been nice if the PublicationMeta class could have held a TCM to its immediate parent(s) and child(ren) pubs.